how to decode privatekey into bs58 acceptable by wallets?
I'm trying to encode a privatekey into bs58 and login into wallets but it says its not in the correct format. However i'm encoding into bs58 and even decoding to make sure i'm getting the same original bytes, wich according to the logs are correctly decoding and encoding, here is my snippet
use solana_sdk::signature::{Keypair, Signer};
use bs58;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let keypair = Keypair::new();
    let public_key = keypair.pubkey();
    let secret_key = keypair.secret().to_bytes();
    let bs58_encode = bs58::encode(secret_key).into_string();
    let bs58_decode = bs58::decode(bs58_encode.clone()).into_vec();

    println!("Chave Pública: {}", public_key);
    println!("Chave Privada: {:?}", secret_key);
    println!("bs58: {:?}", bs58_encode);
    println!("bs58 decode: {:?}", bs58_decode);
}

    Chave Pública: 5cBhgaZ6Tjq8AhGWjPeGavdqv6nh6mQnab9g23LUgmKV
    Chave Privada: [190, 254, 81, 191, 188, 251, 2, 110, 124, 255, 154, 228, 12, 147, 48, 115, 138, 224, 49, 33, 213, 236, 238, 139, 148, 114, 85, 177, 208, 82, 32, 60]
    bs58: "DrZPGNoMRaP9snVhjLRZEgLKcQHvzNJ2JBZCiK9UJeS7"
    bs58 decode: Ok([190, 254, 81, 191, 188, 251, 2, 110, 124, 255, 154, 228, 12, 147, 48, 115, 138, 224, 49, 33, 213, 236, 238, 139, 148, 114, 85, 177, 208, 82, 32, 60])

as you can see I'm able to get the original bytes sequence from the encoded string, so I have no idea of what's going wrong

Most wallets expect the secret key to actually be the private key concatenated with the public key. Try this:
fn main() {
    let keypair = Keypair::new();
    let public_key = keypair.pubkey();
    let secret_key = keypair.secret().to_bytes();
    
    let mut combined = secret_key.to_vec();
    combined.extend_from_slice(&public_key.to_bytes());
    
    // Convert the concatenated result to base58
    let bs58_encoded = bs58::encode(&combined).into_string();
    
    println!("Base58 encoded result: {}", bs58_encoded);
}

If against expectation that doesn't work, try switching around the endianess.

Thanks it worked, I tried this but unifying by hand. If you dont mind just to confirm, you:

encoded the pubkey to bytes
concatenaded both as bytes on the same vector
and just then parsed the full vector to base58


Yes your analysis is correct, that's exactly what I did. Glad it worked! Make sure to accept the question so others know this has been resolved :)
